# Set transition speed relative to height

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, css, css-animations

I'm building a collapsible directive in Angular, and I would like to adapt the slide open/close speed to be relative to the elements' height.

Something along the line of this:

```
app.directive('slider', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (element, attr) {
            // wrap tag
            var contents = element.html();
            element.html('<div class="slideable_content" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');

            return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                // default properties
                var dur = ((element.clientHeight / 100) * 0.1) + "s";
                console.log("duration", dur);
                attrs.duration = (!attrs.duration) ? dur : attrs.duration;
                attrs.easing = (!attrs.easing) ? 'ease' : attrs.easing;
                element.css({
                    'overflow': 'hidden',
                    'height': '0',
                    'transitionProperty': 'height',
                    'transitionDuration': attrs.duration,
                    'transitionTimingFunction': attrs.easing
                });
            };
        }
    };
});

app.directive('sliderToggle', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.expanded = false;

            element.off("click").bind('click', function (e) {
                var target = document.querySelector(attrs.sliderToggle);
                var content = target.querySelector('.slideable_content');
                if (!attrs.expanded) {
                    content.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                    var y = content.clientHeight;
                    content.style.border = 0;
                    target.style.height = y + 'px';
                } else {
                    target.style.height = '0';
                }
                attrs.expanded = !attrs.expanded;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

As you may or may not see, `var dur` is where I try to do this. For as far as I can see, this doesn't work.

Is there someone here who can help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure attrs.duration is undefined? try.

```
app.directive('slider', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function (element, attr) {
        // wrap tag
        var contents = element.html();
        element.html('<div class="slideable_content" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');

        return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            // default properties
            var dur = ((element.clientHeight / 100) * 0.1) + "s";
            if (attrs.duration) {
              dur = attrs.duration;
              console.log('using attrs.duration as duration!', attrs.duration)
            }
            attrs.easing = (!attrs.easing) ? 'ease' : attrs.easing;
            $(element).css({
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'height': '0',
                'transitionProperty': 'height',
                'transitionDuration': dur,
                'transitionTimingFunction': attrs.easing
            });
        };
    }
};
```

});

Comment: That's what `attrs.duration = (!attrs.duration) ? dur : attrs.duration;` is for :-)

Comment: Did you validate what attrs.duration is after that line?

Comment: Since it doesn't exist yet, it gets set to `dur`. It seems as though `element.clientHeight` is causing the problem.

Comment: Ok, maybe i don't get your question. Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lv1kjzg/1/ this works as expected. Hope this helps you in some direction. Good luck.

Comment: My question is to adapt the transition speed to the height of the element. Shorter elements get a shorter transition speed, higher elements get a longer transition speed.

Comment: ok check out the fiddle. Use clientHeight on an element use height() on a $.element.